# JWT dont accept Authorization with Bearer

Tags: python, flask, jwt, swagger, swagger-ui

I was trying to use swagger with flask as docs api

the problem i get now is that when the request sended use This header

```
Authorization: Bearer <jwt_token>
```

I get this error  :

```
{
  "description": "Unsupported authorization type",
  "error": "Invalid JWT header",
  "status_code": 401
}
```

when i use

```
Authorization: JWT <jwt_token>
```

All work great , so any good implementation to fix this with swagger and make it use **JWT** and not **Bearer**

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue, the solution is to use the headers as such

key: Authorization

value: jwt {token}

as simple as that.

Comment: This worked for me. Authentication type: "API KEY"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about changing the swagger stuff, but if you are using flask-jwt-extended you can change the rest of your flask application to also use JWT instead of Bearer to keep everything consistent. See the JWT_HEADER_TYPE option here: http://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#header-options